# When I convert from GLB to FBX, the texture is lost, any advice?

Tags: texturing

Hello I've been trying to find a solution to this issue and was hoping someone could help
(this is in blender btw)

I then export it as an fbx, after doing so I then reimport it back into blender as an fbx. Upon doing that all I see is my 3d model but without texture.

Any advice as to how I can get the texture to remain after converting from .glb to fbx. Thank you :)

Comment: Look at the shader node graph after importing. The base color texture needs to be plugged directly into the Principled BSDF Base Color socket for the FBX export to work.

Comment: thank u so much i will try that right now